# Notation for all sets with a given cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a notation for the collection of all sets with cardinality $k$, for some integer $k$? [This collection is not a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839347/collection-of-sets-with-a-given-cardinality-kappa-is-not-set), but it is still a useful collection. For example, suppose this collection is denoted by $\mathcal{S}[k]$. Then, given a set-family $H$, we can write:

$$H\cap \mathcal{S}[k]$$

to denote the elements of $H$ with cardinality $k$.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but for the set of all subsets of $H$ having cardinality $k$, I see to recall I've seen notation something like $[H]^k$.  Unfortunately it's impossible to google.

Comment: @NateEldredge This is the standard notation. I'm pretty sure that one can find this is Kunen's or Jech's books on set theory. Also, since we usually denote the universe by $V$ or $U$, I think one could write $[V]^k$ or $[U]^{k}$ to denote the desired class.

Comment: This is the class of [$k$-subsets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Subset.html) of the [set universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) $V$. It can also be written as $\binom{V}{k}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, in set theory we use $[X]^\kappa$ to denote the set of subsets of $X$ of size exactly $\kappa$. Here $\kappa$ can be an integer, or a transfinite cardinal.

If I had to choose a notation which would be recognizable to a set theorist, I'd use $[V]^\kappa$, where $V$ is the set theoretic universe. You can use other letters if $V$ has a different "usual interpretation" in your context.